# Can I modify Android's protocol stack?

Tags: android, protocols

Can I modify Android's protocol stack? Can I replace the IP protocol with another protocol?

Comment: may be yes, if your elaboration is good

Comment: why the hell do you need to do such thing ??

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to achieve: asking about that might get you a more useful answer :).

Answer (score 0):

You *can*: it's all open source.  As Andy Rubin famously (almost) said:

```
mkdir android
cd android
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync
make
```

Rip out the IP code from the kernel and write whatever you want in its place :).

That said: I suspect you don't actually want to do that, it would be an awful lot of work and probably not be much use afterwards.  However, it's not clear at the moment what you're actually trying to achieve...

Comment: Thanks, I'm a student, my lab will do a research about the next-generation Internet. we will use other things instead of IP to routing.So, in order to do this research with android, we need to modify the IP protocol. now, I just do some Feasibility Analysis of this work, thanks very much

Comment: hanson, I may have answered the question you asked, but you should almost certainly *not* actually do this: to my knowledge, most research in this area augments IP rather than ripping it out, and operates in user-space not kernal space.  You might find the Serval project an interesting look at what's going on in the mobile space.  If you do want to modify the kernel, you're probably better off starting on a VM, rather than on a phone.